# fopen auto complete changing directory

Tags: directory, debian, fopen

Working on a C program in Debian and I need to access a directory that has numbers at the end of it that occasionally change.  When accessing from the command prompt I can tab complete or use the *, how can I do this from a C program using fopen or some other method?

```
pwm = fopen("/sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_P8_19.15/duty // this is the changing directory
pwm = fopen("/sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_t*/duty // this did not work
```

Comment: Also tried changing directory char *directory = "/sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_t*";
  int ret;
  ret = chdir (directory); 
  pwm = fopen("duty", "w");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using stdio.h, stdlib.h, unistd.h

```
int k = 0;
char pwm_path[100]; 
for (k = 14; k < 20; k++)
{

    sprintf( pwm_path, "/sys/devices/ocp.3/pwm_test_P8_19.%d/period", k );
    puts(pwm_path); //debug
    if (access( pwm_path, F_OK ) == 0) // if it finds path, then = 0
        {
        //printf("Files does exists, %d\n", k); // debug
        pwm = fopen( pwm_path, "w" );
        fseek(pwm,0,SEEK_SET);
        fprintf(pwm,"20000000"); // pulse period in uS
        fflush(pwm); // flush free up memory
        break; // break out of loop once found
        }
}
```